# merging 2 string lists

Tags: c#, list

suppose I have 2 lists

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>;
list1.Add("one");
list1.Add("three");
list1.Add("five");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>;
list2.Add("two");
list2.Add("four");
list2.Add("six");
```

how could I go about merging them (technically not concatenating) so that I can get a new list with the values:

```
[one two] [three four] [five six]
```

Note that the '[' and ']' delimits each string in the final list. So the first value in the list is 'one two', the second value is 'three four' and the third value is 'five six'.

I hope I explained it in a clear manner.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `Enumerable.Zip()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linq function you want is [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var list3 = list1.Zip(list2, (s1, s2) => s1 + " " + s2);
```

Output:

```
IEnumerable<String> (3 items)
---------------
one two 
three four 
five six
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if your lists have different numbers of items?

Comment: It will combine elements until one of the collections runs out of items.

Comment: Additional elements will be discarded. Check out the documentation in the link above. It has a sample.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize that was a link. Thanks!